# Помогите исправить ошибки (E016, C2660)

Tags: c++

2 oшибкe в строке 29 :1)Ошибка - E016  слишком мало аргументов в вызове функции 2)Ошибка - C2660    k: функция не принимает 1 аргумент

```
#include <cmath>         
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double k(double, double);
double k1(double, double);

void main()
{

    double p, q, h, j, k;
    cout << "p=";
    cin >> p;
    cout << "q=";
    cin >> q;
    cout << "Вiдповідь:" << k1(p, q);

}
double k(double x, double y)
{
    double f = sin(x) / y * y + cos(y) / x * x;
    return f;
}


double k1(double p, double q)
{
    double d = ((pow(k(1.0 + p), pow(q, 2))), 2) - k(q * p, 1) / (1 + k(pow(p, 2), q));
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Господи... Ошыбка

Comment: ДА! 
Она самая.
..........

Comment: @Тарас посмотрите внимательно вот сюда: `k(1.0 + p)` - тут явно только один аргумент

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем коде функция k принимает 2 аргумента, Вы пытаетесь вызвать её в функции k1 используя только 1 аргумент:
double d = ((pow(**k(1.0 + p)**, pow(q, 2))), 2) - k(q * p, 1) / (1 + k(pow(p, 2), q));
Аргументы для функций указываются через запятую, попробуйте заменить k(1.0 + p) на k(1, p)